# error Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am in process of building my own site. This error suddenly show up under woocommerce smartcoupon during checkout process when add 2 or more gift certificate and press send to different people. Any ideas whats wrong? Thanks in advance

Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/babypa7/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213

```
    $value = call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 1, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));
```

screenshot are following.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnO9R.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp92r.jpg

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to describe the problem. Rather than posting links to images of your code and the error messages, please edit your question to include them as text.

Comment: You have posted the error code, that tells you exactly what is wrong. `html_entities_decode()` requires a string and you are passing it an array value.

Comment: sorry, i am kinda lost here, didnt know much about complicated coding. Plugin.php is core file, maybe something in child theme i shouldnt change?